# Is it possible to keep a component of my iOS app running all the time?

Tags: ios, service, messaging

I have to implement a messaging system that uses XMPP in my app. The messaging system should be running even if the user has quit the application. What I'm looking at is something similar to how facebook iOS app shows new notifications.

Would it be possible to keep a certain component of my app running in the background even if the app is not running?

Comment: I guess that in FB app they use Apple Push Notification Service, and when you receive a new message, the server sends you a Notification. Apple is a bit picky with things running in the background.

Comment: I think you are talking about push notifications. Please google for that. Facebook gets it as push notification. You cannot run an app which user choses to force quit. It can only run in background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only a few apps that can truly run in background. Quoting the iOS App Programming Guide:

> - Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
> - Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
> - Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
> - Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
> - Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

Your app is neither, so about your only option is using the Apple Push Notification Service, as does the Facebook client app.